# Want to make a border transparent for multi color backgrounds

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a simple shape and want to make the actual grey borde transparent to allow me to place the image on a multi color background.

[image: make the grey border transparent]

How to do that please ?

I followed a lot of tutorial but I want make i work in my case.

My example file is here: https://we.tl/sg9f3ccq35

Thanks.

Comment: If the grey border is the stroke of your shape, you can simply remove its color. Then it's invisible. Hopefully you have some fill that is visible. Find the appearance panel, There is plenty of control available in a single place.

Comment: Question needs clarification... but I think I might be following you. Is the image at [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks0Op.png) the sort of effect you're after?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the way you have constructed the image has made this difficult. You have several objects grouped, overlaying each other, some with strokes, and some with fills.  To make this easier, you need a single shape.

Here's what I would have done:

1. Use the Ellipse Tool, and Rectangle tool to make the basic shapes. Add a black stroke, and no fill.
2. Select all the shapes, open the Pathfinder, and click the Unite button.  Then add a white fill to the object.
3. Reduce the opacity of the stroke in the appearance panel. In the example below, I have applied a 50% opacity to the stroke.
4. In the Appearance panel, click on the bottom most Opacity option, and choose the "Knockout Group" option

You can view the transparency against some coloured shapes placed behind.

[image: Screenshot showing Illustrated Steps]

When you have finished, you can output the artwork in a format such as PNG which supports transparency.  Here is the finished PNG image, with a 50% transparent border and solid white fill.

[image: Example PNG image]